# Wordpress add_filter inside function not works

Tags: php, filter, wordpress

I will try to explain my case.

I would like to change the **wpseo_title, wpseo_metakey, wpseo_metadesc, wpseo_opengraph_type, wpseo_opengraph_image, wpseo_title,** and **wpseo_opengraph_image_size** on the "archive-page" of "custom post"

Because yoast plugin not translated meta tags inside "archive" post. And i need to translate all

I have this code:

```
function get_archive_seo() {

include 'seo_archive.php';

$tipoSel = get_post_type(get_the_ID());

if(is_post_type_archive( $tipoSel )){

    foreach ($traduccionesArchive as $keyTipo => $tipo){
        foreach ($tipo as $keyMeta => $palabra){
            if($keyMeta == 'opengraph_type' || $keyMeta == 'opengraph_image_size') continue;
            icl_register_string ('my-theme', $keyTipo." - ".$keyMeta, $palabra);
        }
    }

    foreach ($traduccionesArchive[$tipoSel] as $key => $palabra){
        add_filter( 'wpseo_'.$key, function($nombre) use ( $palabra, $tipoSel, $key ) {
            if($key == 'opengraph_type' || $key == 'opengraph_image_size') return $palabra;
            return icl_t('my-theme', $tipoSel." - ".$key, $palabra);
        });
    }

}

}

add_filter( 'wp_head', 'get_archive_seo');
```

And this is the **"seo_archive.php"**:

```
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['title'] = 'Hotel, Vacaciones en Andalucia';
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['metakey'] = 'palabra1, palabra2, palabra3';
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['metadesc'] = 'Mapa de Hotel en Andalucia, Costa del Sol, Costa de la Luz y Sierra de Grazalema. El lugar ideal para tus vacaciones.';
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['opengraph_type'] = 'object';
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['opengraph_image'] = 'http://www.hotel.com/img/logo.png';
$traduccionesArchive['hoteles']['opengraph_image_size'] = 100;

$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['title'] = 'Apartamentos de vacaciones Costa del Sol ';
$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['metakey'] = 'palabra1, palabra2, palabra3';
$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['metadesc'] = 'Mapa de localizacion de los Apartamentos Vacacionales de Hotel. Disfruta de tus vacaciones en familia en la Costa del Sol.';
$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['opengraph_type'] = 'object';
$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['opengraph_image'] = 'http://www.hotel.com/img/logo.png';
$traduccionesArchive['apartamentos']['opengraph_image_size'] = 100;

$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['title'] = 'Mapa de localizacion de Hotel, Andalucia';
$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['metakey'] = 'palabra1, palabra2, palabra3';
$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['metadesc'] = 'Mapa de Hoteles en Andalucia, en los destinos vacacionales de Costa del Sol, Costa de la Luz y Sierra de Grazalema Andalucia.';
$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['opengraph_type'] = 'object';
$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['opengraph_image'] = 'http://www.hotel.com/img/logo.png';
$traduccionesArchive['destinos']['opengraph_image_size'] = 100;

$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['title'] = 'Ofertas Hotel Costa del Sol, Costa de la Luz ';
$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['metakey'] = 'palabra1, palabra2, palabra3';
$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['metadesc'] = 'Ahorra en tus vacaciones con las ofertas en nuestros hoteles de la Costa del Sol, Costa de la Luz y Andalucia.';
$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['opengraph_type'] = 'object';
$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['opengraph_image'] = 'http://www.hotel.com/img/logo.png';
$traduccionesArchive['ofertas']['opengraph_image_size'] = 100;
```

But now, it not works, but in the past works fine, the filter is form module yoast SEO https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/

Y tried with this [Wordpress: How to return value when use add_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797313/wordpress-how-to-return-value-when-use-add-filter/13797597#13797597)

I'm a little confused because this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', function(){return 'foo';}
```

Works outside the get_archive_seo functions, but not works inside function.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, this may help to you.

```
function title_function_name($title) {
    $title = "Your title write here";
    return $title;
}

add_filter('wp_title', 'title_function_name', 15);
if (!has_filter('wpseo_title'))
    add_filter('wpseo_title', 'title_function_name', 15);
```

Comment: In that case it would have to write a function for each type of tag i want to modify. In my function i have all in one "foreach", the question is "Why this does not work?" it worked for a while, and, why "add_filter" not work inside a function?

Comment: @Sakrow We have to keep it outside - for what you're attempting. You usually want WP to set up your filters and actions when it reads in all the PHP, before it has started doing any real output.