# How do I move woocommerce-error before woocommerce wrapper?

Tags: php, woocommerce, add-filter

By default `woocommerce-error` is inside the `woocommerce` wrapper. The `woocommerce-error` `ul` is in the `woocommerce` wrapper. I want to move the woocommerce error message before `woocommerce` wrapper.

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error"></ul>
<div class="woocommerce"></div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I sow that you asking question without knowing the basic so better you see the codex provide by WordPress which will help you have to override functions and add your functions [add_filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)  & here is a good [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797313/wordpress-how-to-return-value-when-use-add-filter/13797597#13797597)

Comment: Post your theme code or which wrapper ?

Comment: What is the goal of moving it?

Comment: Because my woocommerce wrapper have max-width: 750px. And I want the wooocommerce error message full width. So I need to move it before woocommerce wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :
 change this `where_you_want_to_view_the_message` to your desire location of woo hook and

```
function my_woocommerce_add_error() {

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
add_action( 'where_you_want_to_view_the_message', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```

Comment: Thank for the code. I put the code in my function.php, but my error message is not showing up.

Comment: this is just an example

Comment: i don't get it. how do I show the error message :( ?

Comment: You better learn wordpress function [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) & [WooCommerce](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)