# Hook Do-action with Add_action

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am trying to call function, created with `add_action` using `do_action`:

**In the `function.php` of the theme:**

```
function bleute_utbi_service_type()
{

 return "service";
}

add_action('utbi_service_type', 'bleute_utbi_service_type');
```

**Now, I need to get the value of the function in a plugin file:**

// 'x' plugin file:

```
function get_valor(){

$val = do_action('utbi_service_type');
echo "this is the valor:" . $val";

}
```

This way of doing is not working, `$val` return 'null'...why?

Comment: You have to pay attention to the order of the files are loaded. Most likely the do_action is executed before the hook is registered in the function.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with add_action than you have to follow this referenece by passing argument to add_action 
[Reference](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-arguments-to-add_action)

else try using apply filters like this.

add above code in function.php:

```
function example_callback( $string ) {
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'example_callback', 10, 1 );

function get_valor(){
    $val = apply_filters( 'example_filter', 'filter me' );
    echo "this is the valor:". $val; 
}
```

and add below code to wherever you want to print:

```
get_valor();
```

hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Action hooks do not return content, and honestly if you need an `action hook` to return `content` there is a pretty good chance that you are doing something wrong.

> `add_action()` takes the identification of a function, in your case
>   `bleute_utbi_service_type()`, and puts it into a list of functions to be called
>   whenever anybody calls `do_action()`.

Either use `$params` with your `do_action` and `add_action` and then set the `$value` in your `add_action` callback function or use `filters` to return contents. To know how return works with `filters`, u may refer here: [Wordpress: How to return value when use add_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797313/wordpress-how-to-return-value-when-use-add-filter)   or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/